# How to return multiple results in recursive?

Tags: java, loops, recursion

I would like to return all the results "10" in this java method :

```
class Test {

    public int loop(int[][] numbers, int total, int position) {
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers[position].length; i++) {
            int newTotal = total + numbers[position][i];
            if (newTotal == 10) return newTotal;
             else if (position < numbers.length-1) {
                int result = loop(numbers, newTotal, position+1);
                if (result != -1) return result;
             }
        }
        return -1;
    }


    public static void main(String args[])  { 
        Test test = new Test();
        int[][] numbers = { {6, 3, 2, 4}, {5, 4, 2}, { 7, 4, 3}, {2, 6} };
        System.out.println(test.loop(numbers, 0, 0)); 
    } 

}
```

But I have some constraints :

1/ I can't use a global variable such as :

```
int[] results; // It's an object and i don't want to wait
```

2/ Also, I can't stock the result, then return them such as :

```
return results; // The loop can take 5 minutes, i don't want to wait
```

3/ Also, I can't print the results on each loop such as :

```
System.out.println(result); // The view must be independant from my model
```

The only way I see it would be to use a while :

```
While () {
     System.out.println(loop( i ???));
}
```

But I don't know at which "i" I am at each time I get a 10...

Do you know how to solve it ?

Comment: Instead of returning int return `ArrayList<Integer>`

Comment: I can't, the loop can take take 5 minutes to complete, i need an update on each results found

Comment: Only way I can think of is using an external collection it throws the results into and use multi-threading so while one thread writes the values to the collection, the other periodically checks for anything new thrown into the collection and does whatever you're wanting to do with it.

Comment: Could be cool to have some code :)

Comment: Would be helpful if you explained what you're actually trying to achieve, because looking at this code, I have a hard time imagining what requirement you're trying to satisfy.

Comment: I'm trying to do MVC in order to separate the view from my loop.